# Speed regulation for universal motor

Tags: motor-controller, universal-motor

I'm building a grinder, which consists of a shaft on which the grinding wheels sit, and the shaft is driven by a universal motor out of a washing machine via a belt and a pulley.

I'm using an off-the-shelf SCR speed controller.  What I'm finding on the first test run is that the motor slows down a lot when I, e.g., try to sharpen a chisel on the grinding wheel.  I can turn the knob on the speed controller up to get it up to the speed I want while sharpening, but then as soon as I take the chisel away, the motor starts to spin up and I have to turn the speed controller down to stop it spinning out of control.

I realise that this is probably the expected behaviour for such a motor, and you may very well tell me that I'm using the wrong motor for the job, and that a motor such as those in my bandsaw, sander, and drill press is what I need (I don't know what that type of motor is called).  But this is what I have, and I like using things that I have already, unless it really turns out to be too complicated.

So, is there a simple (or less simple, but not ridiculously complicated) way to make the motor run at a more or less constant speed regardless of the load?  I'm open to mechanical or electronic solutions (the motor has a tacho coil), either off-the-shelf or DIY.

Many thanks!

Comment: Gearing it down much more so that the wheel runs at the right speed unloaded, the motor runs fast, and the load is reduced by the reduction ratio, will go a long way to solving the problem. Otherwise you're looking for closed loop speed controllers.

Comment: Tachometer feedback could be used if you can figure out how to add that to your purchased controller or find a controller to buy that has that feature. There is a technique called IR compensation that increases the voltage when the current is high and reduces it when the current is low. I suspect that may not work very well fir a universal motor. I suspect the drill, sander and perhaps the bandsaw have universal motors that are designed for those loads. A fixed-speed induction motor may be better for the grinder.

Comment: I think a closed loop controller is the way I'm going to go with this, and it looks like I'll have to build it myself (adapting the purchased controller), since I can't see anything suitable off-the-shelf.

Comment: I spoke too soon: [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TDA1085C-PCB-assembled-commutator-AC-motor-50-100-1pcs-new/272989993447) looks like exactly what's needed (TDA1085-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use a SCR control, this would make your universal motor to run like DC powered, but only one half period conduction. The second semi-period is used to measure the BEMF from the motor and to set the phase angle.

Now probably you already have such control (post the schematics). If it doesn't work correctly it is possible due to incorrect setting (gain), or maybe yours is just too simple.

Another possibility is to add a tacho to the machine and then use a phase angle speed controller like TDA1085.

Comment: I don't have a schematic, but it's one of [these](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4000W-220V-AC-SCR-Voltage-Regulator-Dimmer-Motor-Speed-Controller-Module-Tool-UK/124533020284).  I'm wondering if I could adapt it and replace the speed pot with some sort of MOSFET controlled by an MCU that would take a reading from the tacho coil...

Comment: I'll take a look at the TDA1085 too, thanks.

Comment: @Alex I guess, those are just dimmers without BEMF regulation. With TDA you have to install the tacho.

Comment: I found and ordered [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/400W-AC-220V-Motor-Speed-Controller-Pinpoint-Regulator-Controller-Forward/154282368987).  Don't know if it's TDA based (will look when I get it), but it takes a reading from the tacho (which the motor has fitted already), so it seems to be what I need.